# What is the difference between available "close Android application" code?

Tags: java, android

I have an application and the launcher activity is a login activity. I want the user to be able to close the app in another activity and when he opens it again the application to start again from the login activity (in other words to close the app and not just send it to background).

I have found a lot of ways to close an app:

`1.finish();`

```
2. Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);

3. finishAffinity();
4. finishAndRemoveTask();
5. System.exit(0);
```

and combinations of the above. Which one is more efficient? What is the best practice?

Comment: tried finishAffinity(); ?

finishAffinity(); will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use whichever one you like. `System.exit(0)` probably is the most efficient, being a system method that directly exits the JVM running your app.